# Como arcar uma div para dentro com css

Tags: html, css

Como fazer esse arco na div com css ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei com border-radius: 0px 0px 100% 0px; mas não fica legal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Adicione o html e o css se não fica difícil te ajudar né amigo!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode tentar utilizar apenas o border-radius da direção que você quer criar o radius.

tenta isso:

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border-top-left-radius: 400px 200px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3y7tk91d/1/)

Comment: Que significam os valores de  border-top-left-radius: val1 val2?

Comment: o border-top-left-radius manipula o radius dos valores top e left sepradamente, enquanto o border-radius trabalha com valores dividido igualmente. Ex. se eu quiser mexer apenas no border superior esquerdo, vou declarar val1 (borda superior) val2 (borda esquerda)